# How to mix \ref{} and \pageref{}?

Tags: cross-referencing

There is \ref{} and \pageref{}. But I want mixed behaviour. I would like to have something like "XXX (page.YYY)" in text, where XXX is what \ref{} usually produce (chapter/section/etc number), while YYY is page number. How to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Think about how this should work if the `\ref` points to something on the same page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a new command like `\fullref`

```
\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{%
  \ref{#1} 
  (p.~\pageref{#1})%
  }
```

And call

```
\fullref{label}
```

That is a MWE which doesn't test page. I suggest, as @Mico said, to use https://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref. The author of the package has thought to you :-)

Comment: Thanks! I need to learn basic macro processing in TeX :)

Comment: Possibly better with `p.~\pageref{#1}`

Comment: that is LaTeX, not tex. You will find easily on internet the basic of \newcommand. Here, we have a command with only one argument. We send it (#1) to other commands.

Comment: inded, egreg you are true

Comment: or `\cpageref{#1}` with `cleveref`

Comment: indeed, this example is too simple and don't try the page number. I didn't know varioref, but it does everything for you.

Comment: oups, sorry. corrected ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into the [varioref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package and its `\vref` macro. The macro has the following properties:

- if the item being cross-referenced happens to be located on the *same page*, it behaves like the plain `\ref` macro, i.e., nothing is appended;
- if the item is located on the immediately previous or following page, it appends "on the preceding page" or "on the following page", as appropriate, to the cross-reference;
- if the item is located somewhere else in the document, the string "on page " is appended to the cross-reference.